# How to make an onShow onHide event for jQuery for only applied element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code, to enable on-`show` and on-`hide` events. So, for example when I make a `DIV` visible, it will automatically call my custom function and do appropriate changes on the DIV at that moment automatically.

```
 (function ($) {
      $.each(['show', 'hide'], function (i, ev) {
        var el = $.fn[ev];
        $.fn[ev] = function () {
          this.trigger(ev);
          return el.apply(this, arguments);
        };
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

The problem is, it is called when any other element inside that main `DIV` is `show()`ned too.

So, when I do

```
$('.mother').on('show',function(){
    if(...){
        $(this).find('.child').show();
    } else {
        $(this).find('.child').hide();
    }
});
```

for

```
<div class="mother">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

It goes to infinite loop, as in `jQuery` `on()` method requires a selector for the second parameter and it is triggered for an event that happens on the children too if that second parameter is omitted or null.

I couldn't define that second parameter.
So making it

`$('.mother').on('show','.mother', function(){`

does not work, as it is already the mother...

I do not want to type:
`if(event.target != event.delegateTarget){return;}`
to every single callback function and I couldn't do it in the plugin code too as it doesn't have event object there...

These were what I have tried.
How can I solve this?
What can be the alternatives?

I want to be able to bind `onShow` functions to specific elements which shall never be called on events those happen on it's children.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a custom function after show / hide on some elements and on others not you shouldn't change the `$.fn.show() / .hide()` itself. Instead you can pass your function as a callback parameter to `.show() / .hide()`:

```
function custom() {console.log('custom: ', this);}

$(".mother").show(custom); // ---> custom: <HTMLElement>
```

Note that the callback is executed after show / hide have finished. So if you call them with duration:

```
$(".mother").show(2000, custom);
```

custom is executed 2 seconds later.